# Apache error log - DNS lookup failure for: hostname

Tags: java, apache, jboss, dns

I am in the midst of performance testing a web application and I get these errors in Apache logs

> [Sat Apr 18 03:01:01 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xxx.253] proxy: DNS lookup failure for: jboss-host-name returned by /some/url, referer: http://f5hostname/context/URI

It occurs only at high load levels which indicates that it may not be the configuration that is causing it. I have seen posts where this error occurs due to incorrect proxy configuration, but my case doesn't fall under that I guess. At the very end of the test I get another error - "All workers are in error state". I think the first DNS error causes all workers to shutdown.

Can someone point where I could start looking? Please let me know if you need more details than whats mentioned below.

**More details:**

Apache version: 2.2

mod_cluster: 1.2.4.Final

I have an F5 in front of two Apache servers. There are ten JBoss servers in the balancer.

Apache configuration snippet: (I am not using proxypass, just modcluster)

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit, StartServers and worker related attributes configured here
</IfModule>

ProxyPreserveHost On
MemManagerFile /var/cache/httpd

<VirtualHost *:1280>
    ManagerBalancerName some2
    ........
```

Jboss config:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.1">
    <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" proxy-list="host:1280,host-2:1280" balancer="some2" advertise="false" excluded-contexts="invoker,jbossws,juddi,console" connector="http">
        <dynamic-load-provider>
            <load-metric type="busyness"/>
        </dynamic-load-provider>
    </mod-cluster-config>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure we would need more information to fix this, but the amount of information required would be too much to post and be outside the scope of SO. What performance analysis tools have you used on your system?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using load runner to run the test and JvisualVm, openNMS for the JVM (I think this issue is not related to JVM). I am not using any tool for apache's runtime metrics collection. mod_cluster manager status and the general status page provides node information, but I don't see it useful to debug this. I exhausted looking at all the logs and hence wanted to know where to start. I just need some pointers where I could start digging into.

Comment: I drilled into Apache code to find the place where this error is thrown and found the following line `if (err != APR_SUCCESS) {
        return ap_proxyerror(r, HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY,
                             apr_pstrcat(p, "DNS lookup failure for: ",
                                         conn->hostname, NULL));
    }`

Variable err is value from the function call - apr_sockaddr_info_get found in sockaddr.c which has a bunch of logic and if anything goes wrong there, it could be misinterpreted as DNS lookup failure. I will have to dig deep into this.